# How do I install Grub Customizer on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, 20.04

I'm trying to install grub-customizer on Ubuntu 20.04 and it's not working.

This is what I've tried (as suggested by multiple websites):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer 
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

It doesn't seem to find the package:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

This is the output from the last command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer
```

I've read in a few places that people have been able to install this on 20.04 correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Yes! After running this command I am now able to install it: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"` Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

What happens is the ppa doesn't support Ubuntu Focal, so you need to remove the external first.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
```

The good news is, `grub-customizer` exist on [default repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/grub-customizer).

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting exactly the same output after running those commands: `E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer`

Comment: @cltweedie I'd be careful installing grub-customizer. It tends to make a mess of the grub configuration files.

Comment: Stopped working on 23.04 again. Even after adding that ppa.